# Konva JS why scenefunc context.circle is not working?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs, vue-konva

I am trying to create custom share a circle and BIN inside that circle to use as button.
but context.circle is not working in documention they mentioned, rect, circle, text.. we can use with custom shape.

Please letme know what is the issue, is it bug or something i am missing.

```
var rect = new Konva.Shape({
        x: 10,
        y: 20,
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        radius: 10,
        sceneFunc: function (context, shape) {
          context.beginPath();
          context.circle(0, 0, 5);
          context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
        },
      });
```

Comment: Did you try with context.fillStyle set ?

Answer (score 1):

`context` argument is a wrapper around 2D native canvas context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.

You should use its methods to make drawings. In your case you may need `context.arc`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc

Comment: Thanks for guiding me, this is sad that in documentation its not clearly mentioned.
Actually i want to create cirlce and bucket svg inside that as icon to make a button.